# Tamanho de janela em Java

Tags: java, javafx

Quando abro o projeto em JavaFX no SO Windows, ele abre certinho, porém quando abro o mesmo projeto no Mac Retina, ele abre com outra dimensão, as janelas ficam todas desalinhadas e tenho que consertar na mão.

Tem alguma forma de corrigir isso?

Seguem imagens a baixo para mostrar o que está acontecendo.

Windows:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mac:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está usando anchorpane não é? Os monitores tem a mesma resolução?

Comment: Sim, AnchorPane. Não tem, no windows uso 1600x900, no Mac a resolução é maior. Se eu usar uma VBox, será que esse problema resolve?

Comment: Mais ou menos, não tem como ficar o filtro de um lado e o menu de outro no VBox

Comment: Sim sim, o filtro eu dou um jeito depois, mas as janelas de cadastros, ficam fora de ordem tb, creio eu que usando uma VBox esse problema possa ser corrigido. Vou tentar e ver no que da

Answer (score 1):

Como você está usando um AnchorPane (e aparentemente só aquela parte do filtro está fora do lugar) sugiro que você mude a ancoragem dos itens à direita para a direita, pois percebi que você deve ter colocou todos em relação à esquerda, mais ou menos assim:

```
\>--------|---------|----------|--------------------------------|
```

Teria que ancorar em relação à direita a parte dos filtros:

```
\>--------|---------|----------|                      |--------------------<
```

Quantos aos botões você tem que aumentar o width deles para um pouco mais do necessário porque as fontes mudam de sistema à sistema.

Comment: Ahh entendi, vou dar uma testada. Valeu pela dica!!